# Using software keyboard in AOSP custom build emulator

Tags: keyboard, android-emulator

I was finally able to build my own AOSP image, and I want to debug some problem with the software keyboard. However, the default emulator has a physical keyboard emulated, and I don't know how to disable it.

I know that the Android SDK allows disabling the keyboard when creating an AVD, but I was only able to create such AVDs for the platforms that come with the SDK, and not for my own build.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I don't know if it is the best place to do such a modification, but I was able to edit the default emulator skin at

```
development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
```

And set `hw.keyboard=no` there.